# Error implementing methods into button listener

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I try to implement the method into my Button's `onClickListener` and i got an `Syntax Error`.

Below is my code:

```
// button click event
btnCreateNewEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {
// Checking for server respond
if (serverRespond() == false) {
           //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Below is my `ServerRespond` outside the `onCreate` method

```
// Check server respond    
public boolean serverRespond() {
boolean success = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_create_event);
        HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlcon.connect();
        if (urlcon.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(create_error.toString(), "Server is not responding");
    }
    return success;
}
```

ERROR: at `if(serverRespond()==true){`

```
"The method serverRespond() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"
```

Comment: Seems correct. Just clean your project and run it.

Comment: Is this the "only" error you get? I suspect there is some other error preventing the class from compiling and causing this error.

Comment: Accept answer if you have solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can access by doing:

```
YourActivity.this.serverRespond()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling serverRespond() method in following way:

```
this.serverRespond();
```

and as this method is in class implementing OnClickListener, it will search this method in this class or OnClickListener. Either change it to:

```
serverRespond();
```

or

```
YourActivity.this.serverRespond()
```

as per answer of Michel-F. Portzert.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (serverRespond() == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onClick",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}



public boolean serverRespond() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "serverRespond",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```